# MongoDB class diagram

Tags: mongodb, visual-c++, uml, class-diagram

I have imported mongoDB source code to visual studio 2015 and tried viewing the class diagram but it fails to generate the UML.
Any additional steps that could be done? Other resources to see the class diagram and get a better understanding of the source code?

Comment: Are there any error messages to indicate a problem?

Comment: I downloaded the zip from Github and imported it to visual studio by creating a new project from existing code.The error is "Value doesn't fall in range" without any additional details.